# Kivy: Reduce extra spacing between widgets

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a Kivy app that uses a GridLayout with two rows. The first row contains a dropdown button with a list of items. The second row contains a BoxLayout with two labels.

I noticed that there is a lot of space between these two widgets (the dropdown and the labels). Here is a screenshot

[image]

I'd like the "Left Label" and "Right Label" to appear directly underneath the "Select Hero" button. I tried using the 'anchor_x' and 'anchor_y' values, but it doesn't seem to affect the layout.

Here is my main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition  

class HeroScreen(Screen):
    dropdown = DropDown()
    dd_btn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HeroScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        dropdown_list = [
            'Ant Man',
            'Batman',
            'Cat Woman',
            'Danger Mouse',
            ]
        for hero in dropdown_list:
            btn = Button(text=hero, size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.say_hero(btn.text))
            self.dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        self.dd_btn = Button()
        self.dd_btn.bind(
            on_release=self.dropdown.open,
            )

    def say_hero(self, hero_name):
        print "Hero: ", hero_name

class HeroApp(App):
    screen_manager = None

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=NoTransition())
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(HeroScreen(name='hero_screen'))
        return self.screen_manager

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HeroApp().run()
```

Here is my hero.kv:

```
<HeroScreen>:
    rows: 2
    dd_btn: dd_btn_id
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_x: .4
                Button:
                    id: dd_btn_id
                    text: 'Select Hero'
                    on_release: root.dropdown.open(self)

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            width: 400
            size_hint_x: None    
            Label:
                text: "Left Label"
                font_size: "20dp"
            Label:
                text: 'Right Label'
                font_size: "20dp"
```

What is the correct way to get these two rows to appear closer to one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no space between the widgets, it's just that the text of the Labels is in the middle of each Label (which fills the full vertical gap).

You could solve this in multiple ways. The best one will probably depend on what else you want to change later, but a simple choice would be to manually set the height of the Label-containing BoxLayout to something smaller, e.g. 40.

Comment: I had to set it to 100 instead of 40, but this worked thank you.